# How to put a widget textfield inside the chest image like in the photo flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

How can i use stack to solve the problem?

[image]

Comment: yeah. Just define height & width of the Stack like SizedBox( height: ..., width: ..., child: Stack( children: [  Positioned() ] ) ),

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm Trying to Solve your Problem :

Here is Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TextFieldOnImage extends StatefulWidget {
  const TextFieldOnImage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<TextFieldOnImage> createState() => _TextFieldOnImageState();
}

class _TextFieldOnImageState extends State<TextFieldOnImage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Image On Text"),
      ),
      body: Stack(

          children: [
            Image.asset("assets/6lEG8.png"),
            Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 98,top:150),
                child: Container(
                  height: 40,
                    width: 170,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                    ),
                    child: Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, right: 15, top: 5),
                        child: TextFormField(
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                              border: InputBorder.none,
                              labelText: '               0              ',
                            ))))),
          ],

    ),
    );
  }
}
```

[Video Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iPxayfjAnqVcg1m64kD42bD_5cDgAMlN/view?usp=share_link)